# Erro durante Excução da página - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Sou novato em programação mobile, por isso queria um help para tratar um erro que parece que não foi definido pela IDE (Visual Studio).

O caso é que tenho uma tela a qual queria inserir aquele carrossel com cards de promoção (algo semelhante à página inicial da store do google). Eis que durante os testes, o VS não acusa erro no código mas na compilação aparece o problema.

Eu coloquei uma imagem com print do erro. Obrigado a todos!

---

XAML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
             x:Class="JetSolutionsApp.Views.Aba.Parceiros">

        <StackLayout>
        <CarouselView x:Name="slideTopo">
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Text="{Binding .}"
                           FontSize="50"/>
                </DataTemplate>                
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
    </StackLayout>   
</ContentPage>
```

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace JetSolutionsApp.Views.Aba
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Parceiros : ContentPage
    {
        public Parceiros()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

              var nomesCarousel = new List<string>
              {
                  "jose"," maria", "joaquim", "joão"
              };
            slideTopo.ItemsSource = nomesCarousel;

        }
    }
}
```

Este é o erro:

[image: Erro]

Comment: Tente usar `<Label Text="{Binding}" ="50"/>`

Answer (score 1):

Experimente alterar o XAML do `CarouselView` para o seguinte:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="slideTopo" ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding}" FontSize="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>   
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

---

Se não funcionar a solução acima, podemos tentar de outra forma:

### C#

```
namespace JetSolutionsApp.Views.Aba
{
    internal List<string> Nomes { get; set; }

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Parceiros : ContentPage
    {
        public Parceiros()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Nomes = new List<string>()
            {
                "josé",
                "maria",
                "joaquim",
                "joão" 
            };

            slideTopo.ItemsSource = Nomes;
        }
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<CarouselView x:Name="slideTopo" ItemsSource="{Binding Nomes}">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="50"/>
        </DataTemplate>   
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Comment: Boa noite João, eu experimentei a alteração que me sugeriu mas o erro permanece. Eu procurei por erros de codificação mas não ha nada, apenas esta falha.

Comment: Resposta editada.